# Method to change the position of cursor(caret) according to the condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

About `contenteditable = "true"`, I want to make it impossible to delete `.icon` in this. (`.Icon` always comes last.)

I'm trying the following code.

```
<h2>
  <span class="txt" contenteditable="true">World</span>
</h2>

<h2>
  <span class="txt" contenteditable="true">Hello<span class="icon" contenteditable="false">★</span></span>
</h2>

<style>
h2 {
    word-break: break-all;
}
span.txt {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: text;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<script>
document.addEventListener ('click', event=> {
  let selection = event.view.getSelection();
  let target = event.target;
  let doc = target.ownerDocument;
  let icon = target.closest ('.icon');

  if (icon) {
    let e = icon.previousSibling;
    if (e) {
      let range = doc.createRange ();
      let len = e.length;
      range.setStart (e, len);
      range.setEnd (e, len);
      selection.removeAllRanges ();
      selection.addRange (range);
    }
  }
}, false);
</script>
```

Sample:https://jsfiddle.net/46fjdaxz/

The above code has made it impossible to delete `.icon`.

In the "World area", the caret is displayed when clicking anywhere, but the caret is not displayed when clicking behind "Hello area".

How can I get caret display in the "Hello area"?

Thank you in advance for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Even in your code I could delete the icon: Just by clicking after icon and pressing backspace and it was removed for me.

but for your purpose I could suggest this one:
https://jsfiddle.net/bardc04j/

Just separate the editable part from non-editable one

```
<h2>
  <span class="txt" contenteditable="true">Hello</span>
  <span class="icon" contenteditable="false">★</span>
</h2>
```

Also I just removed your css to place the icon next to the text.

hope to help.

Comment: Thank you for the useful advice. Please try adding CSS. In that case, the line of ".icon" will change. I do not want to change the line of "icon". Thanks.